# Why is the odbc function dbConnect in R splitting the uid string and overriding the server argument?

Tags: r, azure, odbc

I am trying to connect to an Azure SQL database using ODBC with an Azure Active Directory account with password authentication. I think the error is best shown as it's weird:

```
library(odbc)

con = dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                driver = "SQL Server", 
                server = "myserver.database.windows.net",
                database = "mydb",
                uid = "myname@myazure.onmicrosoft.com",
                pwd = "xxx")
```

This returns the following error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: HY000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open server "myazure.onmicrosoft.com" requested by the login.  The login failed.
```

It appears ODBC is splitting my username (uid) on the @ sign and using the right-most half as the server name (which is wrong of course), even though I've specified the server name as an argument. Has anyone ever come up against this strange behaviour? I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: (I removed the [tag:rodbc] tag, which is specific to the `RODBC` package, different from the `odbc`/`DBI` packages, in case you weren't aware of the distinction.)